# picture user input without radio buttons java

Tags: java, image, radio-button, user-input

I'm creating a program in which the user clicks on 1 of the 4 images provided as their input to a question. After answering the question, the window is to go to the next question. How would I go about this? Should I use cases for the images or is their a more efficient way?

For example: 
The question says which image is of Dora?
*There will be a image of Dora, Brad Pitt, Selena Gomez, and Daffy Duck.*
If the user clicks on a image (without radio buttons), the program should save the input and move on to the next question.

My question is more specifically as to how do I make the image the user clicked an input which can saved.

Comment: Store an `int` representing the image clicked? For example, `int answer = 0; if (image was clicked) answer = 1; etc.`

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can make the picture "clickable"? (I don't want to have radio buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is to create JLabels using the ImageIcon constructor, have your class implement `MouseListener`, and then use the `addMouseListener` method for each of your JLabels. Whether you want to create an anonymous `MouseListener` for each one or just use the class instance is up to you. Here's an example that should help get you started:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test implements MouseListener {
    private JLabel imageLabel1, imageLabel2;

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel introLabel = new JLabel("Click an image");
        introLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.add(introLabel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        imageLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image1.png"));
        frame.add(imageLabel1,BorderLayout.WEST);
        imageLabel1.addMouseListener(this);

        imageLabel2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image2.png"));
        frame.add(imageLabel2,BorderLayout.EAST);
        imageLabel2.addMouseListener(this);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getSource() == imageLabel1)
            System.out.println("Image 1 clicked");
        if (ev.getSource() == imageLabel2)
            System.out.println("Image 2 clicked");
    }

    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ev) {}
    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ev) {}
    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) {}
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ev) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```